# Use epsilon delta to prove $x^2+1/x^2+2$ is continuous at $x=1$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Use $\epsilon - \delta$ definition to prove that the function $f(x) =
>  \frac{(x^2+1)}{(x^2+2)}$ is continuous at $x=1$.

I think I am setting the problem up correctly and end up with 
$\frac{1}{3}|x+1||x-1||$$\frac{1}{x^2+2} |$<$\epsilon$
Then I do
If $|x-1|<2, \ldots , |x+1|<4$
But I am confused as to what to do with |$\frac{1}{x^2+2} |$|
The final answer should be something along the lines of 
$\delta\min\{2,\frac{3\epsilon}{4},???\}$ I think

I might be missing an essential step or have made a mistake somewhere in the beginning but I am completely lost as to how to complete this problem. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The observation that $x^{2}+2\geq 2$, so $\dfrac{1}{x^{2}+2}\leq\dfrac{1}{2}$ may help. You may choose $\delta=\min\{1,2\epsilon\}$ to get $|x+1|\leq |x-1|+2<1+2=3$, the rest should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that

$$ \frac {1}{2+x^2}<1$$

to get

$$|f (x)-f (1)|<\frac 13 |x+1||x-1|$$

now you suppose that $|x-1|<\color {red}{1}$ since $x $ is not far from $1$.

this additional condition gives

$0 <x <2$ and $1 <x+1 <3$.
then

$$|f (x)-f (1)|<|x-1|.$$

thus you can take $$\delta=\min (\color {red}{1},\epsilon) $$

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+2} $.

$|f(x) -f(1)| =|\dfrac{x^2+1}{x^2+2} -\dfrac{2}{3}| =$

$|\dfrac{3x^2 +3 -2x^2 -4}{3(x^2+2)}|=$

$|\dfrac{x^2-1}{3(x^2+2)}|=$

$|\dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{3(x^2+2)}|.$

Consider $0<x<2$, I.e. $|x-1|<1.$

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $\delta = \min(1,2 \epsilon)$

Then $|x-1| < \delta$ implies

$|f(x)-f(1)| =| \dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{3(x^2+2)}| \lt $

$|\dfrac{3\delta}{3 \times 2}| = |\dfrac{\delta}{2}| \le \epsilon.$